# Local file system access using google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to access my local fie system in Google Apps script. What I really need is to get file attributes (creation date, last modification date, ...) and upload files to Google Drive.
Is that possible ? And if not, is there a workaround for such a thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Not without user interaction.

Try the Google Picker available to GAScripts running as webapps (or addons/sidebars using HtmlService.

https://developers.google.com/picker/

Once upon a time we were able to use SDC but it has been deprecated.